# How to make Extjs Button look a link?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I want to either make a link in Extjs or make a button look like a link and on hover you see the button. They do this in the docs with Code Editor button and the Live Preview button.

[image]

If they do this using CSS, what CSS do I use and when/how to I apply it?

Comment: Which CSS is applied depends on the HTML being used. Please show the HTML and maybe someone can help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I just want a button to function like it does in the Sencha documents. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.button.Button. Through out the documents they have Code Editor and Live Privew buttons that don't look like a button until you hover over them.

Comment: Use a browser debugger, right click on the element, inspect the CSS. It's all there.

Comment: I know how to grab css. That's not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

I recently wanted a LinkButton component. I tried to find a pre-existing component without any luck, so I ended up writing one from scratch. Its implementation is almost entirely CSS-based.

```
/******************************************************************************/
/*** LINK BUTTON CSS **********************************************************/
/******************************************************************************/
a.ux-linkbutton {
    background-image: none;
    border: 0px none;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

a.ux-linkbutton.x-btn-default-small-focus {
    background-color: inherit;
}

a.ux-linkbutton * {
    font-size: inherit !important;
}

a.ux-linkbutton:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: inherit;
}

/******************************************************************************/
/*** LINK BUTTON JS ***********************************************************/
/******************************************************************************/
Ext.define( "Ext.ux.button.LinkButton", {
    extend: "Ext.button.Button",
    alias: "widget.linkbutton",

    cls: "ux-linkbutton",

    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent();
        this.on( "click", this.uxClick, this, { priority: 999 } );
    },

    // This function is going to be used to customize 
    // the behaviour of the button and click event especially as it relates to 
    // its behaviour as a link and as a button and how these aspects of its 
    // functionality can potentially conflict.
    uxClick: function() {
        //Ext.EventObject.preventDefault();
        //Ext.EventObject.stopEvent();
        //Ext.EventObject.stopPropagation();
        //return false;
    }
} );
```

The click handler is a work-in-progress.

The class does have one minor issue: a pseudo-class style is applied after clicking/focusing that I have not been able to remove. If someone fixes it before I do, please, post the CSS for it.

Answer (score 1):

With Ext 4.0.7 I had managed to do the following:

```
View:
...
{
   xtype: 'button'
   ,text: 'Discard changes'
   ,action: 'cancel'
   ,cls: 'secondary-action-btn'
}

CSS:
....
.secondary-action-btn {
    border: none;
    background: none;
}
.secondary-action-btn span {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recall there is an extension called linkButton. You can refer to the extjs forum [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?54602-Link-Button-or-Hyper-link/page7)

Comment: It's not for extjs 4. Or at least the ones I've found.